# Issues with enabling 'jsx' after upgraded react-scripts to latest version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, babel-loader

Due to security vulnerability issues, I upgraded react-scripts from lower to the latest version(5.0.0) and also upgraded webpack version. Application seems working fine in my local environment but the issue is happening only after deployed.

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /app/app/src/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (52:3):

 

  50 |
  51 | const app = (
> 52 |   <React.StrictMode>
     |   ^
  53 |   <Provider store={store}>
  54 |       <BrowserRouter>
  55 |           <App config={config} />

 

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at instantiate (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:63:32)
    at constructor (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:358:12)
    at Parser.raise (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3255:19)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3301:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11245:18)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10890:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10873:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10849:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10687:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10692:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10669:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10630:21)
    at /app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10600:39
    at Parser.allowInAnd (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12280:12)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10600:17)
    at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11513:28)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11164:23)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10890:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10873:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10849:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10687:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10692:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10669:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10630:21)
    at /app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10600:39
    at Parser.allowInAnd (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12275:16)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10600:17)
    at Parser.parseVar (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13255:91)
    at Parser.parseVarStatement (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13096:10)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12679:23)
    at Parser.parseStatementLike (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12584:17)
    at Parser.parseModuleItem (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12561:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13185:36)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13178:10)
    at Parser.parseProgram (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12460:10)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12450:25)
    at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14345:10)
    at parse (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14365:26)
    at parser (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:41:34)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:64:38)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:21:50)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:22:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
    at /app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
    at /app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:189:28
```

Application is created using **create-react-app**. Through documentation I've referred so far, babel and webpack are preconfigured in create-react-app so additional configurations are not required. But I couldn't find any other way apart from adding configurations of .babelrc, babel.config.js, webpack.config.js files in root directory and installing few babel packages as Devdependencies, still getting above error after deployment. I'm thinking that this problem is due to latest version of react-scripts. Correct me if I'm doing wrong or suggest if there's any other way to resolve this issue.

I'm using node version of 14.21.3 and npm 6.14.18. React and react-dom versions are 17.0.1. Recent upgraded react-sripts version is 5.0.0 and webpack is 5.82.0

**package.json:**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "webpack": "^5.82.0"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts",".jsx" , ".tsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:["style-loader","css-loader"]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
};
```

Comment: Did you build the code successfully? Check the build logs

Comment: yes, build ran successfully without any error.